# In binary search why we are addressing last element of an array(end) as arr.length-1 and not simply array.length

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

```java
static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int target){
        int start = 0;
        int end = arr.length -1;
        while(start<= end){
            //find the middle element
//            ind mid = (start + end )/2; // might be possible that the ( start+ end ) exceeds the range of int in java if they are very large values
            int mid = start + (end -start)/2 ; //same thing but this time it will not  exceed the int value
            if(target<arr[mid]){
                end = mid -1;
            }else if(target > arr[mid]){
                start = mid +1;
            }else{
                return mid;
            }

        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

What's the need of writing  `int end = arr.length - 1` and why not `int end = arr.length` if we want to get the end of the array in binary search in java.

Comment: Because arrays start at zero.

Comment: For the same reason that you would use this to get the last element *in any other context*. It has absolutely nothing to do with binary search.

Answer (score 1):

Indexing for Java arrays starts with 0. So, if you define an `arr[10]`, it has elements `arr[0]` to `arr[9]`. Your binary search algorithm accesses these elements for comparison, and trying to access `arr[10]` would be invalid, resulting in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Because array starts on 0, so their last position is always their length minus 1. The array position "length" will be always out of range (an IndexOutOfBoundsException).